# Подсчет количества перестановок в алгоритме слиянием

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сортировка

Задание стоит именно такое и я понимаю что как таковых ,перестановок у этого алгоритма нет,есть только деление массива до единичного размера и сравнение таких массивов.
Как все же подсчитать количество смен позиций в массиве?

Comment: Можете уточнить: объединяем массивы [1,3] + [2,4] = [1,2,3,4] - т.е. изменилось положение двух элементов, это две перестановки, исходя из вашей задачи? Или вот еще кейс: [3,4] + [1,2] = [1,2,3,4] тут все элементы сменили свои позиции - это 4 перестановки? Или вариан проще, или сложнее уж не знаю, [2]+[1] = [1,2] это одна перестановка (один раз обменяли элементы местами, или две - 2 элемента сменили свои позиции? Просто не очень понятно что именно считать

Comment: @rdorn вот собственно и мне не особо понятно что считать.В  сортировке пузырьком всё ясно,а как быть с этим алгоритмом?Если мне нужно подсчитать **количество перестановок** в этом алгоритме.
Использую рекурсивную реализацию.

Comment: _[2]+[1] = [1,2] это одна перестановка (один раз обменяли элементы местами, или две - 2 элемента сменили свои позиции?_ А, может, три? buffer=(1);(1)=(2);(2)=buffer;

Comment: У преподавателя или одногрупников спрашивать не пробовали, что имел ввиду автор задачи? А так почти любой возможный вариант считается довольно легко.

Comment: @Akina не, это детали реализации, к тому же не всегда явно используется буфер, бывают всякие swap-функции, так что это обычно не считают, но от этого не сильно легче

Comment: @rdorn сама задача целиком выглядит так. Исследовать эффективность работы двух алгоритмов сортировки.Сортировку пузырьком и сортировку слиянием.Вывести время затраченное на сортировку 10к элементов и количество перестановок.
как уже и говорил,с пузырьком все и так ясно.
Сравнили значения,поменяли местами(если нужно) и пошли дальше.

Comment: ну в таком случае все просто, у слияния ровно N*log(N) перестановок, независимо от исходного состояния массива, у пузырька - от 0 до N^2 в зависимости от исходного состояния. Таким образом, несложно сделать вывод, что на малом числе элементов пузырек эффективнее, а на большом наоборот

Comment: @rdorn в общем просто выводить число исходя из формулы  не париться? (в случае с слиянием)

Comment: не знаю, не я вам задачу ставил =) но по сути так и есть, если считать именно перемещения элементов, включая обязательный для слияния буфер

Comment: Вообще довольно странно сравнивать количество перемещений, т.к. пузырек может не сделать ни одного перемещения, но время его работы все равно будет O(N^2)

Comment: @rdorn, что же поделать?Какую задачу поставили на курсовую,такую и выполняем.Да еще и должны доказать про ее важность в наше то время (и актуальность)

Comment: Ну тогда лучше возьмите Кормена, и посмотрите его теоретические выкладки на эту тему.

Comment: Подмените перестановки *сравнениями* :)

Comment: @Harry, та этому алгоритму все равно насколько упорядочен массив,так что количество сравнений будет одинаковым.